# How to responsively format a single row table inside bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to incorporate a newsticker in my navbar. To achieve this I formatted a single row table. I made a table because I want to have the title of the newsticker separate from the news-items, so I can have them in a -tag, scrolling from right to left like newsticker on tv.

The basic set up is as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
         <li>
            <table width="100%" border="0">
               <tr>
                  <td> <font color="red">NEWS</font></TD>
                  <td>
                     <marquee>Active now: 13 +++ </marquee>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

I made a jsfiddle for visualisation: https://jsfiddle.net/gv86j5c9/

My problem now is as follows: How can I format the newsticker responsively so that it balances with the rest of the nav-menu-items in a single nav-menu-row? My newsticker is a little too long, so it gets put beneath the nav-menu items. However I want it to automatically shrink when the screen isn't large enough to fit the newsticker and the nav-items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I thought it would give you something else to think about if you aren't restricted to having the marquee in the menu. Due to the nature of the old marquee tag, I'm not sure you will be able to get it working how you'd like. Additionally, you would be extremely limited on space for the marquee in the 768px - 992px range going down your road. However, there are some intelligent people on here, so someone may be able to find a way for you.

Below is my suggestion if you aren't against an alternate look/solution.

[Here is a Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gv86j5c9/2/) of what I'm referring too.

For this, you only need to make a few simple changes:

- Move your `enjoy-css` div outside of your header
- Set the margin on your `enjoy-css` div to 0 (at least for the top-margin)
- Make the margin-bottom for `navbar-default` 0 as well, so the newsticker is flush up against it

**EDIT/NOTE**

I'd also like to point out that the `<marquee>` tag is not particularly good to use. It lacks in browser support and is not a standard HTML tag.

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some
>   browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any
>   time. Try to avoid using it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Alternatively, you can use CSS3 or a javascript/jQuery plug-in.

CSS3 Example - http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/xxuxd/

jQuery Plug-in - https://plugins.jquery.com/marquee/

Comment: That looks great!! I just implemented it and am very happy with the result, thank you so much for the suggestion and the infos! :)

Comment: @sardine Not a problem, glad to help out!